# Difference between unsymmetric and anti-symmetric relations?

Tags: relations

I am finding difficulty in understanding the difference between asymmetric (non-symmetric) and anti-symmetric relations. Though I didn't quite find any mention of the word asymmetric in the reference book, our teacher had mentioned it while explaining the concepts.

So my question, are **non-symmetric** and **anti-symmetric** relations, both the same thing or different? It would be appreciated if someone could explain using a couple of examples. (I did not understand the definition, so I did not approach the sums, hence this is a general question.)

Answer (score 1):

A [symmetric relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation) is one where the order can be flipped. Equality is symmetric because if $x=y,$ then $y=x$ also. Weak inequality $\leq$ is also symmetric. Strict inequality $<$ is not symmetric.

An [antisymmetric relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation) is one where distinct elements cannot be reversed. Weak inequality is antisymmetric.

An [asymmetric relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_relation) is one where the equation never holds. Asymmetric means antisymmetric and irreflexive. Strict inequality is asymmetric.

Comment: How is weak inequality symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

Denote $R$ the relation.

*Non-symmetric* is just $\:\lnot(aRb\implies bRa)$, whereas *anti-symmetric* is $(aRb)\wedge(bRa)\implies a=b$.

Comment: You've left behind the quantifiers, and yes it does matter; $\neg (\forall a,b (aRb \to bRa))$ is not the same as $\neg (\exists a,b (aRb \to bRa))$ and also   $\neg (\forall a,b (aRb \to bRa))$ is not the same as $\forall a, b (\neg(aRb \to bRa))$.

Comment: @Rick: Yes, I intentionally didn't add them to make a more intuitive sketch. I don't think the O.P.'s difficulties are at that level. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, you are right. The difficulty level is not too high, just the beginners.

Comment: @Rick Though it is not mentioned in our book, I am quite intrigued in knowing the difference between your second statement.  ¬(∀,(→)) is not the same as ∀,(¬(→)). I know that "for all" is very much different than "there exists", but the second statement is quite new to me.

Comment: Should I post a new question in accordance to this, or will it be okay if you edit your answer here?

Comment: It is the same as $\;\exists a\exists b\bigl(\lnot(aRb \to bRa)\bigr)$. If can be further simplified, as $p\to q$ is $(\lnot p)\vee q$. So it finally becomes $\;\exists a\exists b\bigl( (aRb)\wedge(\lnot(bRa))\bigr)$.

Answer (score 1):

The definitions are as follows:

- A relation $R$ on a set $X$ is *symmetric* if for all $a, b \in X$, $aRb$ implies $bRa$.
- A relation $R$ on a set $X$ is *non-symmetric* if it is not symmetric; i.e. there exist $a, b \in X$ such that $aRb$ does not imply $bRa$.
- A relation $R$ on a set $X$ is called *antisymmetric* if for all $a, b \in X$, $aRb$ and $bRa$ implies $a = b$.

One can see that non-symmetric and antisymmetric relations are quite different through easy examples. One stock of examples for antisymmetric relations is given by directed graphs; take $X = \{1,2,3,4\}$ to be the set of vertices of graph and define the relation $R_1$ on $X$ as follows: $$a R_1 b \iff \text{there is a directed edge from } a \text{ to }b.$$ A concrete example witnessing non-symmetricity for $R_1$ would be the following graph: $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
1 @>>> 2\\
@VVV @VVV\\
3 @>>> 4
\end{CD}$$ Then $R_1$ is non-symmetric, since $2 \to 4$ (i.e. $2R_14$) but $4 \not\to 2$ (i.e. it is not the case that $4 R_1 2$).

Finally, for antisymmetric relations you can take any [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) on a set, such that the standard $\leq$ relation on the integers or the reals, say.